# Meteor with ViewModel package not updating accross multiple child templates

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor, and have a basic understanding of what is going on, but I am stuck with this example (the problem has been simplified as much as possible):

I have a template, and a child template:

```
<template name="test">
    {{#each items}}
        {{> testItem}}
    {{/each}}

    {{#each items}}
    {{> testItem}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="testItem">
    <div {{ b "click: toggle"}}>{{value}}</div>
</template>

Template.test.viewmodel({
    items: [],
    onCreated: function() {
        this.items().push({ value: 'test' });
    }
})

Template.testItem.viewmodel({
    toggle: function() {
        this.value("changed");
    }
});
```

The thing here is we have a single array of items in the viewmodel, and we render it through a child template multiple times.

When we toggle the item, it only toggles the single item template, not the other representation of it.  It is behaving like it is copying the value, or some sort of scoping is taking place.

My expectation would be the second item to also change, but this is not the case - what am I missing, or misunderstanding here?

**EDIT - Additional Investigation**

If I change the item through the parent, and notify it has changed, the changes propogate throughout the child templates

```
      Template.testItem.viewmodel({
    toggle: function () {
        this.parent().items()[0].value = "changed";
        this.parent().items().changed();
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, when you do `this.value("changed");` you're changing the value of the testItem view model, not the parent array. If you're going to modify the properties of objects in an array I highly recommend you use a client side Mongo collection instead. It will save you a lot of headaches.

```
Items = new Mongo.Collection(null);

Template.test.viewmodel({
  items: function() {
    return Items.find();
  },
  onCreated: function() {
    Items.insert({ _id: "1", value: 'test' });
  }
})

Template.testItem.viewmodel({
  toggle: function() {
    Items.update({ _id: this._id() }, { value: 'changed' });
  }
});
```

btw, I rarely check SO. You will get quicker responses on [viewmodelboard.meteor.com](https://viewmodelboard.meteor.com)